Logical Pluralism and Anti-Psychologism
Are there any forms of logical pluralism which reject psychologism? It seems that logical pluralism is predicated on the notion that the diversity of logic is attributed to the diversity of thought. If one, like Frege, rejects that logic is internal to the mind, and therefore external and real, it would seem there might still be an argument for justifying a plurality of logics on the grounds that there are causes for plurality external to the plurality of minds.

What is your reason for thinking that there is a connection between logical pluralism and psychologism? Unless you explain that, you are just asking people to try to imagine what the connection is and argue against their own guesses.

Updated the question based on the presumption of the train of thought that inheres to the question. Feel free to roll back.

Any form of logical pluralism hints there may not be universal laws of thought/psychology as naively conceived by philosophers since ancient, not unlike the unrestricted predication of totality of collections solely based on their perceived or conceived features in Russell's paradox...

Logical pluralism does not need to be motivated by psychologism or the idea that logics are rooted in how people think. Different logics can be understood as pertaining to different domains of application and hence of having different rules and different semantics.
For example, classical logic is bivalent and features a consequence relation that preserves one of two values. If we choose to accept that all propositions are true or false and never both then classical logic can be thought of as a logic that is truth-preserving. Given true premises, a classically valid argument provides a guarantee that the conclusion is also true. The logic does not describe how people think, but shows how propositions are related to one other.
In many-valued logics, we allow more than two values. Typically we then select one or more of those values as designated values and devise a logic that preserves them. No psychology involved, just relations of consequence between propositions.
In intuitionistic logic, there is no finite valency. Intuitionistic logic can be thought of as preserving constructive provability. From constructively provable premises, an intuitionistically valid argument guarantees a constructively provable conclusion. Again, no psychology, just consequence relations.
The same can be said for other non-classical logics. Like all logic, they are in the business of exhibiting what follows from what. In many cases this can be understood as preserving some property of interest to us. Probability logic features a criterion for preserving probabilities. Relevance logic may be thought of as preserving information. Linear logic may be thought of as preserving the integrity of resource-bound interaction.
In each case, it is natural to ask of a given logic, what are its semantics and what consequence relation is it aiming to describe? The answer will vary depending on the domain of application, but it is not varying because different people think differently (though they do).

A useful clarification on this answer could be to elaborate on the empirical aspect of logical pluralism.  The thinking is that there are an infinity of different logics, and the issue one then wants to investigate is which of these logics is the one applicable to a particular problem or aspect of our universe.  This answer would then elaborate on WHY psychlogism is not relevant.  Instead the selection of logic for a particular aspect of our world would be a contingent empirical question, not a discretionary personal inclination.

@Dcleve Good point. If we hold an anti-exceptionalist view of logic, i.e. that it is not in principle different from other branches of science, then in the same way that theories are underdetermined by data, maybe we could also say that logics are underdetermined by data.

Bumble -- whether it is argued explicitly or not, in science fields we DO treat "what logic to use" as an empirical question.  Empiricism itself uses four state logic.  The logic of causation in Newtonian physics did not limit itself to the push/contact causation of Descartes and Leibnitz.  Superposition of states and virtuality are elements of quantum logic, but not for macro scale objects.  These are all exceptions to the use of classical logic which we apply in many reasoning questions.  What logic we end up using  -- is pragmatic, based on empirical success!
